# MySQL Get "id" from select

Tags: mysql, select

I have a select statement:

```
SELECT id, content, name
FROM records
WHERE type = '1'
  AND name = 'test';
```

Here's the output:

```
id      content     name
99708   10.6.252.41 server01.example.org
```

What I'd like to do is be able to get the `id` that is returned from the previous statement and USE the `id` as input into another statement (an `UPDATE` statement)  that will increment the value of a single column in the same table.

An example `UPDATE` statement that I am wanting is:

```
update records SET hits = hits + 1 WHERE id = ID_FROM_SELECT;
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: He didn't read my mind, because it's not what I want. I'll update my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [user defined session variables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-variables.html) for this if the `SELECT` is returning just one result:

```
SELECT @id:=id AS id, content, name
FROM records
WHERE type = '1'
  AND name = 'test';
```

Then, on the same database session (connection), do the following:

```
UPDATE records
SET hits = hits + 1
WHERE id = @id;
```

I'm assuming you're doing something with the selected records in your app, and you're trying to save on performance by avoiding having to search for the record again in the `UPDATE`. Though, in that case, why not set the 'id' value as a parameter in code?

Obviously, if the `SELECT` is returning multiple records, this would best be done in code as I mentioned above, otherwise you're left with running the `SELECT` query again as a subquery:

```
UPDATE records
SET hits = hits + 1
WHERE id IN
  (SELECT id
  FROM records
  WHERE type = '1'
    AND name = 'test');
```

So, then, it makes more sense just to apply the same filter to the `UPDATE` instead:

```
UPDATE records
SET hits = hits + 1
WHERE type = '1'
  AND name = 'test'
```

Comment: Nice solved this problem.Like.
but what should be done for some rows (for example 10 rows).for each rows,get `id` and then update `hits` = `hits` + 1 ?

Answer (score 0):

Probably this is not what you want to do.

- First of all...If the query only returns 1 line, the solution provided by Marcus Adams works fine. But, if the query only returns one line, you dont need to preset the id in order to update. Just update it:

> ```
> update records
> set hits = hits + 1
> where type = '1'
> and name = 'test'
> ```

- Second...If the query will not return only one record and you want to update all records returned with same values or calculations, the same code above will do what you need.
- Third, if the query does not return just one record and you need to update each record returned with different value then you need to have a different approach.

I think you are not designing your system very well. If the request for update come from outside, you should have the id to be updated as a parameter of your request. For example something like:

```
<html>
 <body>
   <a href="update.php?id=15">Test</a>
 </body>
</html>
```

And in your update.php you have something like:

```
<?php   
     $id = $_GET['id'];   
     $sql = "update records set hits = hits + 1 where type = '1' and name = 'test' and id = $id";   
?>
```

Of course, the picture I have is to small. Probably you have a reason to do this way or this is just an example. If you fill us up with more info we might be more helpful.